# What is the name of the connectors in the Alchitry boards?

Tags: identification, connector

[This](https://alchitry.com/boards/cu) is the Alchitry Cu board

[image: A picture of an Alchitry Cu board]

I need the connectors that fit in there, i.e. these

[image: The connector I want]

Are these any kind of standard connectors? What's their name?

Comment: Bing calls it "        Board to Board Double Slot Male and Female Connector - 50 pin, 0.5mm

Comment: Yandex calls it "Board to Board Double Slot Female Connector - 50 pin, 0.5mm - PRT-16890 - SparkFun Electronics"

Comment: Note in general these may be called "mezzanine" and "board-to-board" connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not standard. 99.99% of connectors aren't.

Normally you would just read the Alchitry documentation because this is critical info. It's in there unless someone messed up.

Unfortunately, they chose one from an unheard of Chinese company 4UCON which means you can probably only get it through Alchitry, not more mainstream channels. That's the other reason not to just list what the connector part number is.

How did I figure this out? It wasn't in the documentation which is ridiculous so I went to the Alchitry webpage to look. The Alchitry site has manufacturer drawings under the "documents" tab where they sell the connector:

[image: connector drawing]

(Image source: [Sparkfun - Board to Board Double Slot Male Connector - 50 pin, 0.5mm](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16891) - [Drawing](http://www.4uconnector.com/online/object/4udrawing/19022.pdf))

---

[image: connector drawing]

(Image source: [Sparkfun - Board to Board Double Slot Female Connector - 50 pin, 0.5mm](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16890) - [Drawing](http://www.4uconnector.com/online/object/4udrawing/19008.pdf))